# How to convert from .aif files in OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, file-conversion

I have these two .aif [AIFF-C audio] files that I need converted into lighter formats in macOS 10.11 (El Capitan).

Exporting to seemingly any format in Audacity results in no more than harsh static.

- `http://audino.us/site/assets/files/1229/54_wores.aif`
- `http://audino.us/site/assets/files/1227/band_practish.aif`

How is it possible to successfully export these to another audio file format (preferably lossless)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

The AIF files are compressed with the IMA 4:1 audio codec and Audacity is choking on how to open those files. So Audacity is just loading the files as compressed files without decompressing them at all. Open the AIF files in question in “QuickTime Player 7” and then export it into any other format you want.

#### Long Answer

I just downloaded and opened up both of your AIF audio files in macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) and playback in QuickTime is 100% fine. But if I load them into Audacity (2.1.2), playback is immediately just a pile of static noise. Very odd.

Opening the files up in “QuickTime Player 7” (which is still available in Mac OS X and located in the “Applications > Utilities” directory) shows that the AIF files have a format of IMA 4:1. This is a compressed audio format so my guess is for some reason Audacity loads the file in without actually decompressing it. Thus the piles of static on playback.

So with the file still open in “QuickTime Player 7,” I went to “File > Export…” and set the file to be exported as “Sound to AIFF” using the default settings. Be sure to save the file with a new name so as to not overwrite the source AIF.

The resulting AIF shows a format of 16-bit Integer (Big Endian) which is an uncompressed format that can be loaded directly into Audacity and can be exported into whatever format you wish.

That said, of course you can export directly out of the “QuickTime Player 7” itself, but I have always found Apple’s export options in that player a bit limiting. So decompressing and using it in some other tool is my best advice to you.